# Scaling two situations

Tags: scale, normalize

I have two situations:

Situation A:

> 0.4588

Situation B:

> 0.0021, 0.0128, 0.0072

As situation A has one value and situation B has three values, I want to generate situation C with only a single value that represents / scale all these four values.

I tried with normalization of data but my conditions is different (as I thought). Is there any way to scale / normalize this condition?

Thanks,

Waqas.

Comment: How could such a thing be done in a general basis? I go to gym on Mondays and Fridays, can I normalise it as Wednesday?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález yeah, I don't get it either:(